# Django: Getting foreign key value to show in forms

Tags: python, django

I have been studying and playing around with django with my test app and I would like to request assistance regarding this matter.

I have the following models:

```
class Job_Posting(models.Model):
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Job_Position

class Courses_list(models.Model):
    Abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Course = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.Abbreviation

class Educational_Requirement(models.Model):
    fkey = models.ForeignKey('Job_Posting')
    Course = models.ForeignKey('Courses_list')
```

This is pretty much straight forward in the admin, adding job posts and assigning the course required. My problem is with the `Educational_Requirement` because I am displaying it in my frontend via form's `ModelChoiceField` and overriding the `queryset` to display the right choices.

The dropdown display's `Educational_Requirement object` and I want it to display the value of `Course` in `Educational_Requirement`. I can't use `__unicode__` in `Educational_Requirement` as it returns an error:

`coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Courses_list found`

Do I really need to set the `__unicode__` in the `Educational_Requirement` and add the string field? I can't do it because it would really break the purpose of why I did it or is there a better way to implement this? Many thanks.

Feel free to comment if you have any tips for a newbie and it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you naming class attributes with capital letters? It's against the convention and looks very confusing.

Comment: Dully noted, it's a bad habit of mine to capitalize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the display value for `ModelChoiceField`, you could easily define your own field and override `label_from_instance` method:

```
class CourseField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         # return the field you want to display, which is Course
         return obj.Course

class EducationalRequirementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Course = CourseField(queryset=Courses_list.objects.all())
```

Not related, but your are suffering from some poor coding styles. Models are python classes, so they should be like `EducationalRequirement`. Fields are python class attributes, they should be lower case with underscores like `job_position`. Check [python PEP8 documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more code style information.

Comment: Thanks, and dully noted :)